# On horizontal scroll of overflown div, fill in progress bar

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a div which contains an image. The container of this image has `overflow:scroll`, so that the user can scroll left or right to see the rest of the image.

I've also implemented a progress bar, which should indicate how much of the image remains to scroll. I.e. if the user has scrolled 5% to the right, it'll fill up 5% of the progress bar (and vice versa).

I can get the function working based on scrollHeight, but can't get it working based on scrollWidth.

Where am I going wrong?

```js
window.onscroll = function() {myFunction()};

function myFunction() {
  var winScroll = document.body.scrollTop || document.documentElement.scrollTop;
  var width = document.documentElement.scrollLeft - document.documentElement.clientWidth;
  var scrolled = (winScroll / width) * 100;
  document.getElementById("myBar").style.width = scrolled + "%";
}
```

```css
.imgCont {
  background: black;
  overflow: scroll;
  position: relative;
}

.imgCont img {
  width: auto;
  max-width: none;
}

.progress-container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 8px;
  background: blue;
}

.progress-bar {
  height: 8px;
  background: red;
  width: 0%;
}
```

```html
<div class="imgCont">
  <img src="https://i.imgur.com/KhWo66L.png">
</div>

<div class="progress-container">
  <div class="progress-bar" id="myBar"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Isn't that what the scroll bar already does?  What system/environment are you displaying this on.

Comment: @freedomn-m - Nope, the blue bar is just the bars empty state. When scrolling right, I want the bar to fill in red (based on how much of the image remains to scroll). I'm testing this on Chrome and Android at the moment, if that answers your question?

Comment: Not really. Looking at this page (the SO question page), I have a scrollbar on the right.  As I scroll down, it shows how far down I am as a percentage of the page.  If I use `div style='overflow:scroll'` and the content is larger, it does the same: the scroll bar shows the percentage of how far I've scrolled.  Your comment mentions red/blue which is not mentioned in the question; the question states an example of 5% - which is what the built-in scroll bar already does.  Perhaps a screenshot of what you're trying to achieve may help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add listeners on the `.imgCont` element and use it's `scrollLeft`, `scrollWidth` and `clientWidth` properties

```js
let scrEl = document.getElementById("scr-el")
scrEl.addEventListener('scroll', event => {
  let scrolled = (scrEl.scrollLeft / (scrEl.scrollWidth - scrEl.clientWidth) ) * 100
  document.getElementById("myBar").style.width = scrolled + "%"
});
```

```css
.imgCont {
  background: black;
  overflow-x: scroll;
  position: relative;
}

.imgCont img {
  width: auto;
  max-width: none;
}

.progress-container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 8px;
  background: blue;
}

.progress-bar {
  height: 8px;
  background: red;
  width: 0%;
}
```

```html
<div id="scr-el" class="imgCont">
  <img src="https://i.imgur.com/KhWo66L.png">
</div>

<div class="progress-container">
  <div class="progress-bar" id="myBar"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

`windows.onscroll` won't emit any events while you scroll horizontally because scroll is happening in the element with class `imgCont`.
put an id `imgCont`

```
<div class="imgCont" id="imgCont">
 <img src="https://i.imgur.com/KhWo66L.png">
</div>
```

and call the on scroll event as

```
document.getElementById("imgCont").onscroll
```

Answer (score 0):

## Jquery solution setps:

1. subtract the visible width of the image and the real image width

```
var winScroll = $(".imgCont img").width() - $(".imgCont").width();
```

2. get the left scroll position

```
var width = $(".imgCont").scrollLeft();
```

3. get the percentage from the width and position

```
var scrolled = ((width / winScroll) * 100);
```

**Check the snippet:**

```js
$(function(){
  $(".imgCont").scroll(function(){
    var winScroll = $(".imgCont img").width() - $(".imgCont").width();
    var width = $(".imgCont").scrollLeft();
    var scrolled = ((width / winScroll) * 100);
    $("#myBar").width(scrolled + "%");
  });
});
```

```css
.imgCont {
  background: black;
  overflow: scroll;
  position: relative;
  height:200px;
}

.imgCont img {
  width: auto;
  max-width: none;
}

.progress-container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 8px;
  background: blue;
}

.progress-bar {
  height: 8px;
  background: red;
  width: 0%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="imgCont">
  <img src="https://static.toiimg.com/photo/msid-67868104/67868104.jpg?1368689">
</div>

<div class="progress-container">
  <div class="progress-bar" id="myBar"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Another solution.

```js
let div = document.getElementById("theDiv")
div.addEventListener('scroll', function(e) {
  let inner = window.innerWidth
  let left = div.scrollLeft
  let sWidth = div.scrollWidth
  let total = sWidth - inner
  let width = 1 * left / total * 100
    
  if (width >= 100) {
    return document.getElementById("myBar").style.width = "100%";
  }
  
  document.getElementById("myBar").style.width = `${width}%`;
});
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.imgCont {
  background: black;
  overflow: auto;
  position: relative;
}

.imgCont img {
  width: auto;
  max-width: none;
}

.progress-container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 8px;
  background: blue;
}

.progress-bar {
  height: 8px;
  background: red;
  width: 0%;
}
```

```html
<div class="imgCont" id="theDiv">
  <img src="https://i.imgur.com/KhWo66L.png">
</div>

<div class="progress-container">
  <div class="progress-bar" id="myBar"></div>
</div>
```